BOEING SERVICE BULLETIN-PARTS ACCOUNTABILITY

In connection with attached page of Boeing service bulletin regarding forward air stair removal, Is the SB only applies to the part numbers which are tabulated in first column from the left(only the tabulated part numbers can be removed per this SB)?

Parts accountability is crucial for maintaining safety & compliance with regulatory requirements. It helps ensure that any modifications or repairs made to an aircraft are done using the appropriate parts & that there is a clear record of what has been done, which is important for both safety & legal reasons. Do you really want to trust the answers given by us random people on the internet with this type of information?  When you called Boeing, what did they tell you?  If you're still in school, what did your instructor tell you?

I'm not student.......

I’m certainly no specialist, but I suppose that if you end up with a removed part which is not on the list, then you removed something you shouldn’t have.
